# Ever responsive to

Tags: word-usage

I came across this sentence:

"Ever responsive to the hobbyist market, Texas Instruments is releasing a [product name and description]"

Is the first part of the sentence implying that the company does indeed respond well to the hobbyist market, or that they rarely do so? I just can't get it.

Comment: Ever the prankster, he glued the teacher's pen to her desk. (Always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries with more than one meaning per word are indispensable.

[*Ever*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ever): at all times; always. -TFD

> *Ever* the gentleman, the Prince, 30, rushed to her aid and scooped up the wayward titfer before returning the garment to its delighted owner...

Often enough (often poetically, sometimes not), they are used together in order to intensify the nature of ever:

> *Ever and always* do the same stories weave themselves into the woof and warp of life, *yet ever and always* is the texture newly colored.